# Thread Pooling in Grails Controllers and Services

Tags: grails, service, concurrency, blocking, controllers

I'm wondering how controllers and services are implemented in Grails. In particular I would like to know, whether and how it maintains a thread pool for both controllers and services.

Assuming following scenario:

> I have a Grails controller that calls a service that does a blocking
>   call to a external system.

Would I need to take care of maintaining a thread pool in the service (or even the controllers), so that when I have multiple user concurrently access my application, the application does not block because of a call in one service?

Comment: what do you mean with 'blocking call to external system'? Does this system accept simultaneous requests?

Comment: I mean a synchronous call (block wait). Yes the external system is able to handle simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make anything specific, on Grails side, each request executed in own thread, concurently.

From official docs: "*By default access to service methods is not synchronised, so nothing prevents concurrent execution of those functions.*" See http://www.grails.org/version/Services/2 ("Services and scopes")

Comment: That's definitely helpful thanks. Are you aware of some more detailed documentation? e.g. is there a way to limit the number of threads spawned for each request? Is there a mechanism to handle scenarios where number of requests grow too big?

Comment: It depends on your web container. For example for Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html (see `maxThreads`)

Comment: What about controllers? E.g. Controller has save action with a lot of objects. Can it block, should I use Thread.new for this?

Comment: But I can't invoke method in service class concurrently. When I call service method multiple times It waits for the first execution to get complete then process the next requests. I think It is placing requests in queues and execute them on their's turn. But I want its concurrent execution. what can be reason of it ? Is '@Transactional' keyword before service class name preventing it to process requests simultaneously ?

Comment: how did you figure out that it waits? please post your code

Comment: Please make it as a new Question here, not in a comments. And also, please make it simpler, nobody will read hundreds of lines of code. Actually its bad practice to have so huge methods, if your method doesn't fit the screen you have to refactor it, or it will be impossible to test this code and support in future.

Comment: Here is the Code of My Servcie Class: http://codepad.org/FjFrjG1Z I just have One Method and I call This Method Multiple times repeatedly for Concurrent Execution. But It doesn't execute them Concurrently and My Remaining Web Application also gets Hang (Stop Working) Until This method complete all executions. Thanks for your interest. Hope to listen from you soon.

Comment: Actually, I don't think one need to read code. Main thing is that why service method is not being called concurrently.